# How to use custom icons in an angular-rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I have a rails app with angularjs and material design at the front end. I want to use a custom icon svg files (something like this).

```
<md-icon md-svg-src="images/fulfill-pos.svg"></md-icon>
```

Though when I add the above line to my html file I get an error "Error: target is undefined" in the console of my browser. It seems it tries to do a get request to 
http://localhost:3000/images/fulfill-pos.svg

How can I use custom icons through the rails asset pipeline? or rather what is the best way to use custom icons/images in a rails-angular based app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put your image in `app/images` directory and use `/assets/fulfill-pos.svg` in your angular views.